# Django - Mix HTML template and queryset in json ajax response

Tags: ajax, json, django

I would like my view to return the page content and some parameters that I would like to use in the Ext.Ajax.request success function.

views.py

```
def importFile(request):
    form = ImportVectorForm()
    html_response = render_to_response("page_content.html", {'form': form, 'folder':folder, 'nodes':nodes},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    if request.POST:
        form = ImportVectorForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            ## here im dealing with the form...
            object = MyObject.objects.create()
            html_response = render_to_response("page_content.html", {'form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
            json_param = serializers.serialize('json', object)
            return StreamingHttpResponse(html_response, content_type="plain/text")

        else:
            html_response = render_to_response("page_content.html", {'form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    return StreamingHttpResponse(html_response, content_type="plain/text")
```

ajax.js:

```
  importFileAjax = function(node_id){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
      method: "GET",
      form: "importForm",
      url: "/basqui/file/import/" + node_id + "/",
      success: function(r){
                  // here I would like to access the model instance created properties
                  Ext.get('table').update(r.responseText); //this update the page content
               }
    });
  }
```

I would like to pass both `html_response` and `json_param` to Ajax. The fist to update a `div` and the second to access its properties.

What is the right way of doing that?

How can I create a JSON that contains the html template as string and the model instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, use `render_to_string` to get the template fragment as an HTML string. Secondy, serialize your object as a Python dict, not JSON. Then you can convert the whole lot to JSON in one go.

```
html = render_to_string("page_content.html", {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
param = serializers.serialize('python', object)
data = json.dumps({'html': html, 'param': param})
return StreamingHttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
```

Now your JS can parse the JSON and access the `html` and `param` values.

Comment: You are very impressive, thank you very much Daniel.

Comment: Is this a generally accepted way of retrieving both HTML and data with a single Ajax request? Elsewhere I've seen recommendations to perform two requests -- one for data and one for HTML. Though I certainly like this suggestion a lot better.